# ProtoBuf serialize exception in WebApi HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I wanna serialize WebApi response as ProtoBuf format.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Foo()
{
    var boo = new BooMolde();
    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(ResponseModel), new ResponseModel
        {
            Status = 1, 
            Data = boo
        }, new ProtoBufFormatter()),
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Ok
    };
}
```

I Used **WebApiContrib.Formatting** as **MediaTypeFormatter** in generating HttpResponseMessage object, internal server error happened and server return below message

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/x-protobuf'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": null,
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: ###",
        "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
        "StackTrace": "   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ThrowUnexpectedType(Type type) in ..."
    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!
**ResponseModel** class dos not had **DataContract and DataMember** Attribute.